# I have read data from txt file and stored in a struct array , and want to sort the data by name field

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This code does not give any errors but displays the array with old 
values without sorting by name field, it works up to reading the txt file storing data in a struct array student an instance of struct person, then when used the code to sort it and print the results of sorted array . but it does not work

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < string.h >

int main() {
    // read data from txt file and stores
    // in a struct array

    storeInarraySort();

}

int storeInarraySort() {

     // struct person with 4 fields
     struct person {
         char name[100];
         char address[100];
         char IDnumber[20];
         int age;
     };


     FILE * file = fopen("personout.txt", "r");

     // declares an struct array to store data
     struct person student[10];

     int k = 0;

     if (file != NULL)
     {
         char line[128]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
         /* read a line */
         while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
         {

             // stores values in struct array
             sscanf(line, " %99[^,], %99[^,], %19[^,], %d", student[k].name,
                 student[k].address, student[k].IDnumber, & student[k].age);
             k++;

         }
         printf("%d\n", k); // no of records in array

         fclose(file);


         // number of records k  r=k first for loop
         // inner for loop s=r+1
         //char temp;
         //struct person temp;

         for (int r = 0; r < k - 1; r++) {
             for (int s = r + 1; r < k; r++) {

                 if (strcmp(student[r].name, student[s].name) > 0) {

                     struct person temp = student[r];
                     //strcpy(temp,student[r]);
                     student[r] = student[s];
                     //strcpy(student[r],student[s]);
                     student[s] = temp;
                     //strcpy(student[s],temp);
                 }


             }


         }

         // prints struct array to check
         for (int t = 0; t < k; t++) {
             printf("%s\n %s\n %s\n %d\n ", student[t].name,
                 student[t].address, student[t].IDnumber, student[t].age);
         }

     }


}
```

Comment: Your problem is a simple typo: In the inner loop over `s`, you test and increment `r`.

Comment: You can use in-built function `qsort()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14300208/4688321)

Answer (score 0):

Use selection sort for sorting.

```
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)  
{  
    int temp = *xp;  
    *xp = *yp;  
    *yp = temp;  
} 

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j, min_idx;  

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
    {  
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array  
        min_idx = i;  
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)  
        if (strcmp(arr[j].name , arr[min_idx].name) < 0)  
            min_idx = j;  

        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element  
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: i want to sort by "name" field which is of type string then how can i adapt the above code to suit my requirement ? can someone suggest a method

Comment: If string a comes before string b in lexicographical order then strcmp(a,b) will be less than zero. If they are equal then it will be zero otherwise strcmp(a,b) will be greater than zero